# Testing Bottling Carbonation

Tags: carbonation, bottle-conditioning, first-time-brewer

So, I bottled 6 days ago. I'm a little impatient, and want to see how my carbonation is going. What can I expect if I pop one open today? I haven't noticed any difference in the beer in the bottle, aside from the expected settling of the final sediment. By 'pop' I mean the 'spssss' sound when opening.

Further, if the cap pops when opened today, is it ready (obviously depends on testing and drinking it)? If not, how long until it's ready, given the pop and carb level after only 6 days?

**EDIT1**
Just put one in the fridge. Will report back in an hour on the status. Here's hoping I get at least a little carb :)

**EDIT2**
Just popped the test bottle. Got the pressure when popping the top, got a slight head. Feels half flat, as expected after only a week. Tastes amazing! This is my first bottle from my first batch. I think I did good, this is a very flavorful beer, good body, aroma, mouth feel. I'm proud to name it 'Frist'.

Comment: You'll want to refigerate the beer for 24 hours before opening. The cold temperature will help the CO2 in the headspace to go into solution, giving better carbonation and head.

Comment: Will keep that in mind. I'm going to let it sit for another week, and am having a tasting party next weekend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a first time brewer, I obviously had a lot of questions.

In this case, in this it came down to RDWHAHB. I sampled a bottle. If you look at my recent questions, after racking to a secondary, I thought I lost the hops aroma. Nope! It's still there, in force. After only a week of bottle conditioning, I still had the hiss on opening. Beer was slightly carbonated.

One more week and I should be done. My Gods This is fun! First batch a winner!